# Glue Spark- Why all task not executing in parallel where number of cores are more

Tags: apache-spark, aws-glue

I see only 6400 task executing where as number of cores are 8000.

1. Input data is s3 parquet snappy compressed.
2. Partitioned on date
3. Bucketed with 6400 files.
4. Join this data set with other dataset which is bucketed having 4800 buckets.

Reading 7 days (7 partition). Number of files to be read: 44,800.

I am sure it should use 8000 task in parallel however it showing reading 6400 select bucket count is 6400.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hard to say for sure without seeing the code that reads and processes the data, and the parameters that you pass. Number of input partitions is determined by data source, it does not need to be the same as the number of your cores. Also, why not repartition immediately after reading and check if spark pushes this down to the source?